# New model added via Studio causes a KeyError on a computed field

Tags: odoo, odoo-13, computed-field

[Odoo v13 cloud edition]

I've added a new model via Studio: `crm.lead.activities`. In that model I have a computed field `x_name`:

Dependencies: x_res_id, x_date, x_activity_type_id

Compute:

```
for record in self:
  record['x_name'] = record.x_res_id.name + ' / ' + str(record.x_date) + ' / ' + record.x_activity_type_id.name
```

`x_res_id` is a *many2one* field to `crm.lead`

But when I try to (un)install a module, I get a KeyError. What can I do to solve this?

```
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/13.0/odoo/http.py", line 624, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/13.0/odoo/http.py", line 310, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/13.0/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 14, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/13.0/odoo/http.py", line 669, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/13.0/odoo/http.py", line 350, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/13.0/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/13.0/odoo/http.py", line 339, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/13.0/odoo/http.py", line 915, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/13.0/odoo/http.py", line 515, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/13.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1326, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/13.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1314, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/13.0/odoo/api.py", line 387, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/13.0/odoo/api.py", line 374, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-66>", line 2, in button_immediate_upgrade
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/13.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 72, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/13.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 634, in button_immediate_upgrade
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_upgrade)
  File "/home/odoo/src/custom/trial/saas_trial/models/module.py", line 99, in _button_immediate_function
    res = super(IrModuleModule, self)._button_immediate_function(function)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/13.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 573, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/13.0/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/13.0/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 369, in load_modules
    registry.setup_models(cr)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/13.0/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 290, in setup_models
    for path in transitive_dependencies(field):
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/13.0/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 276, in transitive_dependencies
    for seq2 in transitive_dependencies(seq1[-1], seen + [field]):
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/13.0/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 272, in transitive_dependencies
    for seq1 in dependencies[field]:
KeyError: x_crm.lead.activities.x_name
```

Comment: You meant `x_res_id` is a _Many2one_ field to `crm.lead`?

Comment: Don't use Studio to add new model !
You are embarking on a very dangerous path. On the surface, the idea is sexy, but behind (in DB), it's an eyesore

Comment: @CZoellner indeed

Comment: @François okay... but as far as I know that's one of the purposes of Studio? Anyhow, I appreciate the feedback, but it's another discussion.

Comment: Yes Studio is ofcourse meant for that, but i'm not a big fan of it either. The produced code is aweful (it's all XML). It not very compatible to other extensions, like community modules. And sometimes it's difficult to find mistakes or rollback things.